# ObjectOutputStream issue when sending data to a socket

Tags: java, sockets, objectoutputstream

I am listening on a server in my program and when cleint sends a message, I first send a 1-byte ACK back, where 1 byte is msgType that I received.

My program execution flow is something like:

```
        Socket connection = null;
        connection = serverSocket.accept();
        connection.setKeepAlive(true);
        logger.info("server: connection received from " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        
        .
        .

        switch(msgType) {
         case 0:
                // MSG_START
              
                logger.info("Received MSG_START");
                        // send ACK
                sendACK(out, 0);
                logger.info("sent ACK for MSG_START");
                     
                break;
       .

        }
```

Then I have definition of sendAck function:

```
private static void sendACK(ObjectOutputStream out, int msgIntType) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    byte[] msgType = new byte[1];
    msgType[0] = (byte) (msgIntType & 0xFF);
    logger.debug("Sending message to client: " + msgType.toString());
    out.write(msgType);
    out.flush();
    logger.debug("Sending msg: " + Arrays.toString(msgType));
}
```

Now problem is that at the client end, when client tried in.read(), it gets byteRead as -1 not 1.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: `read()` returns -1 at end of stream. See the Javadoc. The peer has closed the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectOutputStream is intended for writing Java objects to streams.  In this case, i think you should be using a DataOutputStream (and so should the client).

You would do something like:

```
dataOutputStream.writeByte(0);
```

**EDIT**: BTW, The client should be using a DataInputStream.

Comment: Yep, DataOutputStream is what's required here... that let's you send raw bytes, or ints or floats or whatever...

Comment: I read a lot about people facing problems with DataInput/OutputStream and some string operations not working fine with it. Also in my case, client is AIX and server is Linux, would still DataOutput/Input stream work fine ? We are sending/receiving byte array and converting them to ASCII strings mainly.

Comment: @user656189 I've never had problems with Data[Input|Output]Stream and no problems with communicating in this way between Linux and AIX.  However, in your case, since you seem to want to work with strings internally, can you not simply send ASCII strings?  To send strings you need a simple OutputStreamWriter wrapped in a PrintWriter (for example).  As long as you use the same string encoding on both sides, this should work fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a ObjectOutputStream to send acknowledgement, but this type of stream uses a special protocol as described in the [Java Serialization specification](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html). Such protocol is subject to certain headers sent prior to the actual payload.

Therefore, it is best is you use other kind of stream that is not subject to these decorations.

Comment: Why? Nothing wrong with a special protocol. And it doesn’t explain this specific issue.

Comment: The OP says the intent is to send an ack message back to the client, but if you do that through an object stream, depending on how you do it, the protocol used by the stream will add additional serialization details. If the intend is not to send entire Java objects, a data stream is a better choice for this kind of problem.